# Doctrine/Symfony losing M:N relationships on save

Tags: database, symfony1, doctrine, yaml

I have what I assume is a configuration problem with my Doctrine schema.yml, but I can't see to strike the right answer here.

I have two tables, BetaMeeting and ProjectTester, that form a many-to-many relationship through BetaMeetingAttendee. Everything works fine, and I can edit a beta meeting for example to include several project testers, and the relationships are all saved correctly. However, when I edit a project tester that already has existing relationships with a beta meeting(s), upon save the M:N relationships are lost. Using Symfony 1.4.13 and the admin generator, and Doctrine 1.2, and the edit page for a project tester makes no mention of the many-to-many relationships, no hidden fields, etc. Could this be the reason, the data's not there so Doctrine removes it? I didn't think it would be necessary to include it.

My schema.yml is as follows, with irrelevant details removed.

```
BetaMeeting:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: BetaMeeting
  columns:
    id:              { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    project_id:      { type: integer(4) }
    date:            { type: date }
  relations:
    Project:
      local: project_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: BetaMeetings
    ProjectTester:
      class: ProjectTester
      refClass: BetaMeetingAttendee
      foreignAlias: BetaMeetings

BetaMeetingAttendee:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: BetaMeetingAttendee
  columns:
    beta_meeting_id:   { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: false }
    project_tester_id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: false }
  relations:
    BetaMeeting:
      foreignAlias: BetaMeetingAttendees
    ProjectTester:
      foreignAlias: BetaMeetingAttendees

ProjectTester:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: ProjectTester
  columns:
    id:                  { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    tester_id:           { type: integer(4) }
    project_id:          { type: integer(4) }
  relations:
    Tester:
      local: tester_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Projects
    Project:
      local: project_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: ProjectTesters
```

Any clue as to why the relationships get cleared out after an edit which is concerned only with the immediate attributes of the ProjectTester object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a field defined in the Form but you excluded it from the generator.yml it's like submitting an empty field and therefore it clears the relations.

You have to unset that field in the Form.class so the field retains the current values.

```
public function configure()
{
  unset($this['beta_meeting_list']); // or the correct value
}
```

Comment: Fantastic samura! I hadn't thought about that aspect, but it makes perfect sense, and works like a charm. Out of curiosity, what exactly is it referencing when we say `$this[]`? I'm used to accessing things more like `$this->widgetSchema[]`.

Comment: Well. I don't exactly know the insides of Form. But if you do `$this['beta_meeting_list']` instead of `$this->widgetSchema['beta_meeting_list']`, you unset both widget and validator.